# Error in fromJSON : unexpected character

Tags: json, r, ggmap

I want to work with the function `geocode` in the package`ggmap` in R. But I cannot run the sample code in the R documentation:

```
geocode("houston texas", output = "more")
```

And the result is:

```
Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=houston%20texas&sensor=false
Error in fromJSON(paste(lines, collapse = "")) : unexpected character '<'
```

I wonder if it is the problem with `fromJSON`, so I downloaded the JSON file (as abcd.json) and then import it into R:

```
data <- fromJSON(file="abcd.json")
```

And it works.

But when I do:

```
theurl <- "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=houston%20texas&sensor=false"
data <- fromJSON(file=theurl)
```

It returns the same error:

```
Error in fromJSON(paste(lines, collapse = "")) : unexpected character '<'
```

I tried both `rjson` and `RJSONIO` together with`Rcurl`. It returned errors either way.

---

Relevant information:

1. RStudio Version 1.0.143;
2. R Version 3.4.0
3. macOS Sierra 10.12.6
4. Location: Beijing. (May have something to do with the internet banning of google maps API.)

Comment: and your `geocode()` function doesn't error for me. Perhaps you can try `library(googleway); google_geocode("houston texas", key = "")`

Comment: @SymbolixAU they're using the `rjson` implementation, which does use `file` and not `text`: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rjson/versions/0.2.15/topics/fromJSON

Comment: @miken32 - ah yes - good point.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the invalid character is a `<`, you're likely pulling an HTML error message of some kind. Pulling the data URL directly would let you know for sure:

```
theurl <- "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=houston%20texas&sensor=false"
jsondata <- fread(theurl)
cat(jsondata)
```

I would suggest you try using an HTTPS link instead, it's possible that will get around the issue (unless it's the great firewall.)

Answer (score 0):

I alternatively turned to Matlab, using the toolbox JSONlab.

http://cn.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33381-jsonlab--a-toolbox-to-encode-decode-json-files

The general idea of the rest of the code is pretty much the same as `geocode()`

And it worked.

For those person/institute based in mainland China, a lot of functions in R package `ggmap` is not available (due to the firewall). Use package `geoChina` instead to cope with your project. Baidu API is available in `geoChina`. It's faster than google map API here in China.

Also, if your data is quite large,

```
result <- apply(data, 1, geocode)
```

might return error. Matlab is recommended to deal with relatively large data.